# Push notification does not open app when tapped if the app is in background

Tags: android

Receiving a push notification from Firebase Console does not open app when tapping on it if the app is in background, it only works if the app is in foreground.

Here is my `onMessageReceived` method:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        for (String key : remoteMessage.getData().keySet()) {
            intent.putExtra(key, remoteMessage.getData().get(key));
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_white)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }

        // increment notification number
        PushNotificationHandler.persistNewMessage(this);

        // force a restart for the widget service, if applicable (will be check later)
        WidgetManager.getInstance().attemptStartForceUpdate(this, false);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? I am using Android 12.